# Rails scope policy not accepting additional criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, policy

So in my wiki model I have an attribute for private. If private is true then the wiki should not be viewable to users who are not assign to the wiki_ids via a HABTM relationship.

wiki.rb:

```
class Wiki   
  include Mongoid::Document   
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users  

  field :title, type: String   
  field :body, type: String   
  field :private, type: Boolean, default: false

  scope :visible_to, ->(user) {
    user.present? || user.blank? ?
      where(:private => false) : where(:private => false).or(:id => user.wiki_ids)
  }

  def public?
    !self.private?   
  end   
end
```

WikisController:

```
def index  
  #@wikis = policy_scope(Wiki)  
  #@wikis = Wiki.all  
  @wikis = Wiki.visible_to(current_user)  
  authorize @wikis         
end  

def show  
  @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])  
end 

def new  
  @wiki = Wiki.new  
  authorize @wiki   
end 

def create  
  @wiki = current_user.wikis.build(params.require(:wiki).permit(:title, :body, :private, :user))  

  authorize @wiki
  if @wiki.save
    flash[:notice] = "Wiki was saved."
    redirect_to @wiki
    # report success
  else
    flash[:error] = "There was an error saving your wiki. Please try again."
    render :new
  end
```

I'm pretty confident its the scope that needs to be modified in the model, because if i comment out the scope in the model and replace the index in the controler to Wiki.all. I see all the wikis. 
As of right now as somebody who created the wiki plus flagged it private and I am logged in I do not see that wiki nor does anybody that I add as a user to the wiki.

I tried adding other conditions to the end such as `user.present? ? where(:id => user.wiki_ids)` and `user.present? && where(:id => user.wiki_ids)` but just get errors thrown back at me.

DB entry for User:

```
User_id: 547eb8867261691268000000, wiki_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('54807226726 1690be0260000'),
BSON::ObjectId('5480735c7261690bae000000'), BSON::ObjectId('548
136e57261690aef000000'), BSON::ObjectId('5489af337261690d95000000'),
BSON::Objec tId('5489b57e7261690d95010000'),
BSON::ObjectId('548f9f607261690bb5060000'), BSO
N::ObjectId('54908f127261690be8000000'),
BSON::ObjectId('54908f207261690be801000 0')], name: "Carey VonRueden",
email: "admin@email.com", encrypted_password: "$2a
$10$NrlQ2XH64UucOPcI1aje9.57eoSO74676264YrIjfGvncyGcpGWy",
reset_password_token : nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil,
remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 7, current_sign_in_at:
2014-12-17 18:51:15 UTC, last_sign_in_at: 2014-12-16 02:38:5 8 UTC,
current_sign_in_ip: "10.0.2.2", last_sign_in_ip: "10.0.2.2",
confirmation
_token: nil, confirmed_at: 2014-12-03 07:15:18 UTC, confirmation_sent_at: nil, u nconfirmed_email: nil, role: "admin">
```

DB entry for Wiki:

```
Wiki _id: 54908f207261690be8010000, created_at: 2014-12-16 19:59:28 UTC, updated_at: 2014-12-16 19:59:28 UTC, user_ids:
[BSON::ObjectId('547eb886726169126 8000000')], title: "Private", body:
"Private", private: true>
```

Comment: Answer: So i got the below to work for me. wikiscontroller       def index  
  @wikis = policy_scope(Wiki)        
end

Answer (score 0):

your scope condition is wrong

`user.present? || user.blank?` -> this will be true always. if user is present or user is blank, it will always return only the public wikis

Change your scope to something like below.(assuming you want all public wiki's if user is not signed in. If user is signed in, you want public + the wikis created by user)

```
 scope :visible_to, ->(user) {
    user.nil? ? where(:private => false) : where(:private => false).or(:id => user.wiki_ids)
 }
```

If you are still not getting what you are expecting, check if `user.wiki_ids` is returning the right values

Comment: When logged in shows nothing. The user is referenced in the wiki. see above for DB example.